# Flexslider 2: force selected thumb to middle/center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

## THE PROBLEM

Flexslider is a good slider but i'm having some trouble over here:
When i click to a thumb in `#main-carousel` slider that has the [`asNavFor`](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html) property enabled it will correctly point the `#main-slider` but the selected slide in `#main-carousel` will go out of the viewport. *I want it to stay in the **middle**.*

[image: tiny example here]

### THE CODE

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#main-slider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshow: false,
      sync: "#main-carousel",
      smoothHeight: true
    });
    $('#main-carousel').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshow: false,
      asNavFor: '#main-slider',
      itemWidth: 120,
      itemMargin: 0,
      move: 1,
      after: function(thumbSlider) {
        console.table(thumbSlider);
        var fixed_pos = 140 * (thumbSlider.currentSlide + 1);
        console.log(fixed_pos);
      },

    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.0/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.0/flexslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box full secondo-livello-slider-container">
  <div class="secondo-livello-slider box full" id="main-slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Titolo Immagine 0">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/201/201" alt="Titolo Immagine 1">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/202/202" alt="Titolo Immagine 2">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/202/202" alt="Titolo Immagine 3">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/202/202" alt="Titolo Immagine 4">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/203/203" alt="Titolo Immagine 5">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/204/204" alt="Titolo Immagine 6">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/205/205/abstract/1/" alt="Titolo Immagine 7">
        <span>This Will Positionate Correctly But The Thumb Do not</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/206/206" alt="Titolo Immagine 8">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/207/207" alt="Titolo Immagine 9">
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="secondo-livello-slider-carousel box full" id="main-carousel">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Titolo Immagine 0">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/201/201" alt="Titolo Immagine 1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/202/202" alt="Titolo Immagine 2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/202/202" alt="Titolo Immagine 3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/202/202" alt="Titolo Immagine 4">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/203/203" alt="Titolo Immagine 5">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/204/204" alt="Titolo Immagine 6">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/205/205/abstract/1/TryToClickMe" alt="Titolo Immagine 7">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/206/206" alt="Titolo Immagine 8">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/207/207" alt="Titolo Immagine 9">
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

### THE QUESTION

If you try to click to the 7th thumb you'll see that the thumb will disappear from the viewport. **How to fix? I want it to the center/middle.**

Comment: Guys i've solved it by changing library from FLEXSLIDER to FLICKITY 
http://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#asnavfor